# Why would there be a resistor in parallel with a RF choke?

Tags: rf, inductor

I am a ham radio operator. A few days ago my 100 W 144 MHz linear amplifier stopped working. I dismantled it for diagnosis and repair as these things are usually pretty simple designs.

However, once inside, my mk1 eyeball noticed a burnt out 1/2 W resistor which is not in the schematic. Checking the schematic over, it turns out the amplifier (Microwave Modules MML 144/100s) had been extensively modified at some point in its 33 year life.

The resistor in question was in parallel with one of the two RF chokes in the DC supply rail for the power transistor.

The choke is only a few uH of 10 loose turns wound on a toriodal core about 20 mm in diameter in series with the supply. The ferrite mix is unknown.

I don't understand the purpose of this resistor, let alone how it could have burnt out when its essentially across a short circuit as far as DC is concerned.

Sadly the resistor value is unknown and the colour bands have burnt off.

What might be this resistor's purpose?

Comment: Possibly damping for the choke which itself is an L with parasitic C. That's why throwing in chokes or ferrites beads can cause more harm than good. They can resonate with the parasitics and amplify noise at specific frequencies and if you noise falls into that frequency things get worse.

Comment: If you know the rail voltage and resistor wattage (size), you can estimate an upper value; \$R=\frac{V^2}{W}\$.  So for 50V and 3W, \$\frac{50V^2}{3W} = 833Ω\$.  In parallel with the inductor though, this may be moot.

Comment: The two chokes are in a T configuration with a 1nF cap. Is the one with the resistor the RFC that connects to the transistor's collector, or the one that connects to the power source? I would guess it's the former, and someone was trying to lower the Q by adding the resistor, possibly they were trying to use it out of it's designed frequency range or were having problems with parasitic oscillations. It wouldn't be the DC that caused it to burn, it would be the RF. Edit: I found some pictures and schematic here: http://www.radiomuseum.co.uk/mm.html
So it would be the other choke.

Answer (score 1):

> *What might be this resistor's purpose?*

I've used a resistor in parallel with an inductor on a noisy rail rolling stock power supply to get rid of as much ripple and transient rubbish as possible. The basic idea is the resistor (along with a smoothing capacitor after the resistor) form a good low-pass filter. However, that low-pass is no good for passing several amps of DC so, the resistor is bridged with an inductor that allows DC to pass fairly unhindered.

Clearly, adding the inductor forms a resonant circuit and could, under some circumstances, pose even bigger problems if the noise was incident with the resonant point so, the inductor value was chosen to give a rather mild quality factor and thus not dangerously amplify any noise or transient that had a lot of spectral content at resonance. Basically it was a compromise filter but was useful.

It may be that in your 100 watt PA there is a lot of RF noise on the rails and the inductor || resistor did something similar.

Comment: Or an outright oscillation that someone was trying to kill with the resistor.  If you know the resistor value, you can roughly compute the RF voltage from \$V^2 / R\$ and the fact that the resistor is burnt out.

Comment: @TimWescott that sounds like an alternative answer to me. I tried to focus my answer on what I specifically have done (given the guessy nature of the question) and leave other answers to  er.. maybe you?

Comment: I'd have to see a schematic before I could tell if the power supply to the drive transistors would cause an oscillation, so my comment is more a guess than an answer.

Comment: @TimWescott See my comment above, link to schematic and photos that might be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of the schematic for that, found [here](http://www.radiomuseum.co.uk/mm.html) (Thanks, @GodJihyo).  I've added in the resistor in red.

[image]

That choke is *not* there to provide clean DC to the final transistor.  It's there to isolate the DC supply from the RF on the collector of that final transistor.  Ideally it provides a perfect path for DC, and perfect isolation for AC.  In reality, there can be resonances, and the amplifier can break into oscillation at the resonant frequencies.

Here's a picture of what I think is the choke in question.  Not only is it just a coil of wire in an otherwise strip-line circuit, it's flying across other components.  This is going to cause it to be the source of all sorts of weird resonances.  The circuit will be difficult to analyze, and the coil's parasitic coupling to its surrounding will change any time it's bumped and changes position.  It is (A) pretty standard for a certain era of amateur RF circuit practice, and (B) questionable RF circuit practice.

[image]

It's a very common hack in amateur RF amplifiers to shunt all or some of the final RF choke with a resistor.  The idea is that you reduce the Q of the circuit at frequencies where it is likely to oscillate, while, hopefully, not compromising the AC isolation of the RF choke.

When it comes to resistor sizing, someone aimed, pulled the trigger, and missed.  Or someone modified the thing for intermittent service, then someone else started using it continually.  Whether that resistor in there actually helps or not, it's the wrong power dissipation.  The designer didn't take the AC voltage level into account when choosing the resistor's power level and the resistor cooked itself, or someone bought the amplifier, used it differently than the designer intended, and the resistor cooked itself.

As mentioned before, this resistor isn't going to conduct DC -- but it is going to conduct AC.  So you can determine the dissipation by figuring out the RMS RF voltage at the transistor collector (which is probably less than the DC supply voltage there *if* the amplifier is linear, but could be more if it's class C).  Then you can look at the resistance (if you can read or measure the thing) and calculate the power dissipated by \$\frac{V^2}{R}\$ losses.

If you do the math and find out that it's exactly 1/2 Watt or not too much more, then there's a good chance that the resistor has been slow roasted, and is either still in good shape or the resistance has just risen a bit.  If it's obviously burnt to a crisp -- well, someone chose the wrong power rating.

I'm not enough of an expert to give you a prescription -- if it were my amplifier I'd be very tempted to start by stripping out all the mods and returning it to as close to factory-new condition as I could.  But the suggestions that I *can* give are: first, do the math and make sure that the resistor is big enough; second, make sure you use a carbon composition resistor there, or other resistor that's guaranteed to be low inductance *at 144MHz*; third, consider making the choke out of resistance wire (which will be a **pain** to work with); and finally, do a search on "Q killer" or "shunt RF choke with resistor" or similar -- there's articles out there on why it's generally a bad idea, and what to do instead.

Comment: That's where in the circuit I would have figured it to be, but the OP said it was across the toroidal choke, which is a bit confusing.
But then with the number of hacked up amplifiers I've seen I shouldn't be surprised at anything that's done to one.

Comment: I'm going to leave this stand, unless the OP says otherwise.  And yes, buying used amateur radio equipment is certainly an education in how other people hack up their stuff.  (I don't hack up _my_ radios, of course -- I _improve_ them).